Spark on YARN(EKS) fails because of no credentials
I have a Spark application running on an EKS cluster with YARN
The application starts and i can see it in the YARN UI, but it fails (see screenshot below) because of missing credentials, the defaultFS is a S3 bucket.
In the config i do not specify any credentials provider as the default credential provider chain includes reading from environment variables, and indeed i have environment variables containing access keys in both YARN rm and nm:
    env | grep AWS
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<THE_KEY>
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<THE_KEY_ID>
AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::ROLE_NAME
AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS=regional

The credetials are used successfully at first, indeed i see the .inprogress file in the s3 bucket:

And i see the application directories in the dir specified by the configuration:
spark.yarn.stagingDir: s3a://the_bucket

But soon after it fails reporting that it cant access the s3 bucket, but from the exception i cant understand which part is needing those credentials, i think i am missing some configuraion but i cant get the clue from the exception.
Any tip?


Have you tried to set the env var directly for the executors : spark.executorEnv.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<THE_KEY_ID>
spark.executorEnv.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<THE_KEY>

@Ahmed no, but isn’t the executor in the ‘node manager’ node?

I fixed it by 'injecting' the credentials into spark via configuration:
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key: KEY
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key: SECRET

